# Unsuccessful opening second activity

Tags: android, android-activity

So I am trying to open a second activity from the first activity from a click of a button. The app loads up but then when I try to press the button to go to the next activity nothing happens. Here is my main.xml, mainactivity.java, androidmanifest.xml, shopactivity.java and shop.xml, respectively. Any help is greatly appreciated.

`main.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> 
<RelativeLayout
 xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:text="@string/counter"
        android:textColor="#000000"/>
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView1"
        android:text="@string/gems"
        android:textColor="#000000"/>
    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/textView1"
        android:clickable="false"
        android:cursorVisible="false"
        android:focusable="false"
        android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
        android:textColor="#000000"/>
    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/textView2"
        android:clickable="false"
        android:cursorVisible="false"
        android:focusable="false"
        android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
        android:textColor="#000000"/>
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="310dp"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:background="#000000"
        android:text="@string/button"
        android:textColor="#ffffff"/>
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@+id/button1"
        android:background="#ffffff"
        android:text="@string/button2"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:onClick="onClickShop"/>
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:background="#ffffff"
        android:text="@string/button3"
        android:textColor="#000000"/>
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button4"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/button3"
        android:background="#ffffff"
        android:text="@string/button4"
        android:textColor="#000000"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

`MainActivity.java`

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener{

    TextView textView1;
    TextView textView2;
    EditText editText1;
    EditText editText2;
    Button button1;
    Button button2;
    Button button3;
    Button button4;
    int counter = 0;
    int gems = 0;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
        {super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

    textView1 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView1);
    textView2 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView2);
    editText1 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText1);
    editText2 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText2);
    button1 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
    button2 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button2);
    button3 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button3);
    button4 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button4);
    button1.setOnClickListener(this);
    button2.setOnClickListener(this);
    button3.setOnClickListener(this);
    button4.setOnClickListener(this);}

    @Override
    protected void onStop()
        {super.onStop();
        SharedPreferences prefs = this.getSharedPreferences("com.bugagullgames.clicker", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = prefs.edit(); editor.putInt("key", counter); editor.commit();}

    @Override
    protected void onStart()
        {super.onStart(); SharedPreferences prefs = this.getSharedPreferences("com.bugagullgames.clicker", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        int defaultValue = 0;
        counter = prefs.getInt("key", defaultValue);
        editText1.setText(Integer.toString(counter));}

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v)
        {if (v == button1)
        {counter++;     editText1.setText(Integer.toString(counter));}}

    public void onClickShop(View v)  
        {if (v == button2)
    {
        Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, ShopActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }}}

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest     xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.bugagullgames.clicker" >

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name">
            <intent-filter>
                <action     android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category     android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".ShopActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name">          
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>

public class ShopActivity extends MainActivity
{
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
       super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
       setContentView(R.layout.shop);
}}

<RelativeLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <TextView
        android:text="Welcome to the shop"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

hello @Bugagull define your "ShopActivity.class" in your menifest.

```
 <activity
        android:name=".ShopActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name">

 </activity>
```

and replace this .

```
   public class ShopActivity extends Activity
   {
     @Override
     protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
     super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
     setContentView(R.layout.shop);
      }
 }
```

Comment: I just defined it in my manifest. Unfortunately it did not solve my issue.

Comment: after adding which issue you face?can you send error?

Comment: There was no error, the new xml file wouldn't load. I was overriding button2 OnClickListener.

Answer (score 4):

You are overriding the button2 onclick listener. Remove this line of code:

`button2 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button2);`

And the xml `onclick` property that you configured `android:onClick="onClickShop"` should work.

Answer (score 0):

If you want  use a xml method .

your declaration method must be like it.
public void methodname(View v)

it's important to put this argument.

Answer (score 0):

overriding the button2 onclick listener. Programmatic this show;

```
 button2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                onClickShop(v);
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace `{if (v == button2)`for `{if (v == button2.getView())`or try to find by ID.
I recommend use:

```
button2.setOnclickListener(new OnClickListener {

    // TO DO

})
```